# Want to save facebook image into my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, open-uri, omniauth-facebook

I am using ominauth to signup users in my rails app.i also have a basic signup option with email address also. So for both users i have to save upload user picture in my file system I have regular file upload for my email users but for FB users i want their pics to save in my disc so i can use same code and not use FB graph link while displaying.

FB sends images in this format with graph API

```
http://graph.facebook.com/100007619644580/picture?type=large
```

How can i save that in my public folder where i store all the user images.

i tried

```
directory = "public/data/orig/"
      #name = num1+'_'+params[:upload]['datafile'].original_filename
      name = "new_name_for image"
      path = File.join(directory, name)
      #File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload_hover]['datafile'].read) }

      File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
        file << open('http://graph.facebook.com/100007619644580/picture?type=large').read
      end
```

but it gives me error

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://graph.facebook.com/100007619644580/picture?type=large
```

Let me know if you have any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, Yes i could use the paperclip gem but i'm already using cloudinary to upload image so i didn't wanted to use another image based gem just to force save files from fb user profile. 
I was able to workout the following code changes.

In **omniauth.rb**

```
:secure_image_url => true
```

for last parameters with `:scope` which allowed me and secure URL.

and in my auth controller

```
 img_path = env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["image"].gsub(/$/,'?type=large')
    require "open-uri"

  num1 = 'logo_'+SecureRandom.hex(5)
  img_name = num1+'_fbimage.jpg'
  directory = "public/data/orig/org"
  path = File.join(directory, img_name)
  File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(img_path).read
  end
```

`require "open-uri"` and  `:secure_image_url => true` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use your model to save your facebook image via paperclip
see below :

```
member model
def self.from_omniauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    member = Member.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if member
      member.member_pic =  "https://graph.facebook.com/#{auth["uid"]}/picture?type=large"
      member.save
      return member
    else
      registered_member = Member.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_member
        return registered_member
      else

        member = Member.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
          provider:auth.provider,
          uid:auth.uid,
          email:auth.info.email,
          member_pic: "https://graph.facebook.com/#{auth["uid"]}/picture?type=large",
          password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
          )
      end    
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In **omniauth.rb**

```
:secure_image_url => true
```

Really does the thing.

I have a polymorphic `Attachment` class that I attach to `user.photo`.

Here are my "Interactor" and `Attachment` class snippets:

```html
class CreateAttachmentFromUrl
  include Interactor
  require "open-uri"

  ## Create user service object
  # @param url => url
  # @param user => current_user
  def call
    url = context.url
    user = context.user

    file = nil
    begin
      file = URI.open(url)
    rescue => e
      file = File.open('user_avatar.jpeg', 'wb') do |file|
        file << URI.open(url).read
      end
    end

    context.attachment = Attachment.create!({ user: user }) do |a|
      a.data.attach(io: file, filename: 'user_avatar.jpeg')
    end

  rescue => e
    context.fail!(message: e.message)
  end
end
```

```html
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :data
  belongs_to :user, required: true
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  def url
    if data.attached?
      uri = URI(data.service_url)
      uri.query = nil
      uri.to_s
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```