# OpenURI::HTTPError (500 Internal Server Error) with open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I'm trying to download an image from an URL, the URL is from facebook. I get the URL after I signup with omniauth-facebook:

the steps are the following:

```
$ irb
>> require 'open-uri'
>> open("http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10224315028492218/picture?access_token=EAAPhFIKqb2IBAO6ekZAGnQyoqkxrmoBRAN8Qfc115SJkOzu5wOmCZB6C7IKtql3ZCIEw8NU66RXrmoFZAszU6G3VeXaz7KHZAmS2NVzF5uRKTEonQ43r1ZB8q1otb5MUmEW7YySXcINREet1xG8i1II5apMif97TAxpMoqDXwz9AZDZD")
```

and this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       13: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
       12: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
       11: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
       10: from (irb):8
        9: from (irb):8:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        8: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
        7: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:736:in `open'
        6: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
        5: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
        4: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
        3: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
        2: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:756:in `buffer_open'
        1: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:378:in `open_http'
OpenURI::HTTPError (500 Internal Server Error)
```

trying the same but with https instead of just http:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       12: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
       11: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
       10: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        9: from (irb):12
        8: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
        7: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:736:in `open'
        6: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
        5: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
        4: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
        3: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
        2: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:756:in `buffer_open'
        1: from /home/abdel/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open-uri.rb:378:in `open_http'
OpenURI::HTTPError (400 Bad Request)
```

putting the URL in the browser:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10224315028492218/picture?access_token=EAAPhFIKqb2IBAO6ekZAGnQyoqkxrmoBRAN8Qfc115SJkOzu5wOmCZB6C7IKtql3ZCIEw8NU66RXrmoFZAszU6G3VeXaz7KHZAmS2NVzF5uRKTEonQ43r1ZB8q1otb5MUmEW7YySXcINREet1xG8i1II5apMif97TAxpMoqDXwz9AZDZD
```

it's downloading it without problem, also when I try to use open-uri with another image link, it's working. I don't know why is it causing problem just with the image from facebook.

**Solution**

Thanks to the help of @Gowtham, I manage to download the image and use Active Storage to save it, this was my code:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10224315028492218/picture?access_token=EAAPhFIKqb2IBAO6ekZAGnQyoqkxrmoBRAN8Qfc115SJkOzu5wOmCZB6C7IKtql3ZCIEw8NU66RXrmoFZAszU6G3VeXaz7KHZAmS2NVzF5uRKTEonQ43r1ZB8q1otb5MUmEW7YySXcINREet1xG8i1II5apMif97TAxpMoqDXwz9AZDZD"

begin
  file = File.open('user_avatar.jpeg', 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(url).read
  end
  user.avatar.attach(io: File.open(file), filename: 'user_avatar.jpeg')
rescue Exception => e
  p e.message, e.backtrace.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with HTTPS URL

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10224315028492218/picture?access_token=EAAPhFIKqb2IBAO6ekZAGnQyoqkxrmoBRAN8Qfc115SJkOzu5wOmCZB6C7IKtql3ZCIEw8NU66RXrmoFZAszU6G3VeXaz7KHZAmS2NVzF5uRKTEonQ43r1ZB8q1otb5MUmEW7YySXcINREet1xG8i1II5apMif97TAxpMoqDXwz9AZDZD"
begin
  File.open('test.jpeg', 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(url).read
  end
rescue Exception => e
  p e.message, e.backtrace.inspect
end
```

Comment: great, it seems it is working, how do I access that file later? I mean, I am  needing to attach it with Active Storage, something like this user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: 'test.jpeg')

Comment: @AbdelP. You can use either PaperClip or CarrierWave to do so. Here is the link that has an example for PaperClip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748779/want-to-save-facebook-image-into-my-rails-app#answer-30752617